# Sencha Cmd cannot compile app after upgrade to MacOS X 10.9

Tags: ruby, extjs, osx-mavericks, sencha-cmd

After upgrading my Mac to MacosX Mavericks I have this issue:

```
 MacBook-Pro-Sergey:Komus boooch$ sencha app build
Sencha Cmd v4.0.3.74
[INF] 
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF] 
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] init-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF] 
[INF] init:
[INF] 
[INF] app-build-impl:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-path:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-environment:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-shell:
[INF] 
[INF] init-cmd:
[INF]      [echo] Using Sencha Cmd from /Users/boooch/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.3.74 for /Users/boooch/Documents/SenchaApps/Komus/build.xml
[INF] 
[INF] -before-init:
[INF] 
[INF] -init:
[INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
[INF] Adding antlib taskdef for com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml
[WRN] The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (0.0.0.0), current is 4.0.3.74. Please run 'sencha app upgrade -noframework' to update to 4.0.3.74.
[INF] 
[INF] -after-init:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-init-defaults:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-defaults:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-init-defaults:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF] 
[INF] init:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-build:
[INF] 
[INF] refresh:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-refresh:
[INF] 
[INF] -init:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF] 
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Loading classpath entry /Users/boooch/Documents/SenchaApps/Komus/touch/src
[INF] Loading classpath entry /Users/boooch/Documents/SenchaApps/Komus/app.js
[INF] Loading classpath entry /Users/boooch/Documents/SenchaApps/Komus/app
[INF] Loading classpath entry /Users/boooch/Documents/SenchaApps/Komus/build/temp/production/komus/sencha-compiler/app
```

In this state it freezes with java process loading my CPU more then 90%

[image]

downgrading ruby to 1.9.3 (http://moduscreate.com/sencha-cmd-not-working-in-os-x-10-9-mavericks/) does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!

I run sencha build with debug   **sencha -d build app** and it stops on:

```
[DBG] Detected lazy instantiation reference to Ext.Component in file /Users/boooch/Documents/SenchaApps/Komus/app.js
[DBG] Adding dynamic requirement on Ext.Component to app.js as a GenericAutoDependency
```

The code in app.js was:

```
Ext.define('Ext.Component', {
    override: 'Ext.Component',
    show: function (animation) {
        return this.callParent([false]);
    },
    hide: function (animation) {
        return this.callParent([false]);
    }
});
```

This code is fix for Android 4.3 messagebox not closing issue. When I remove this code all compiles fine. Now I have to found solution to Android issue fix.